# Sequelize: call getters inside where operator

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have Database with `IsBoolean` field.
IsBoolean can be `1` or `0`.
But in Javascript/Typescript I have `true` or `false`. It's more convenient.

I added getter to use pure boolean in Javascript.
I added setter to convert into 0/1 for Database.

Model:

```
const Employee = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('employee', {
        // ...Id...
        IsBoolean: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // Bit: 0 or 1
            allowNull: false,
            get() {
                const value = this.getDataValue('IsBoolean');
                return !!value; // from number to boolean
            },
            set(value) {
                // from boolean to number
                this.setDataValue('IsBoolean', +value);
            },
        },
    }, {
        tableName: 'employee'
    });
};
```

Now I search instance:

```
Employee.findOne(
    {
        where: {
            // getter is not being invoked
            // IsBoolean: true, // doesn't work, Conversion failed
            IsBoolean: 1, // works because I pass number
        },
    },
).then((data) => {
    const result = data.get({ plain: true }); // getter works
});

// setter works
Employee.update(
        { IsBoolean: false },
        { where: {Id: 100} },
);
```

Getter works when I use `get({ plain: true })`.
Setter works for `update(..)` operation.
But getter doesn't work inside `where` (and another operators).

Is there any way to fire getters inside `where`?

---

As variant I can use BeforeFind hook:

```
function propagateRequired(instance) {
    instance.where.IsBoolean = !!instance.where.IsBoolean;
}

hooks: {
  beforeFind: propagateRequired
}
```

But I think it's too difficult.

Comment: Why don't you use DataType.BOOLEAN?

Comment: It's legacy code and database

Answer (score 1):

As a result, I use beforeFind hook

```
function propagateRequired(instance) {
    // or add another operators (in, like)
    instance.where.IsBoolean = !!instance.where.IsBoolean;
}

hooks: {
  beforeFind: propagateRequired
}
```

For getters/setters I can use

- `getterMethods` and `setterMethods` in the model options
- or get/set (see my question) inside each field definition.